# Contentpanes not working in java

Tags: java, swing

I can reply as soon as tomorrow morning (I'm really tired)

source of how I did this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

This line of code is giving me errors:

```
win1.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The part I'm having issues with is:

```
emptyLabel
```

It throws an error and it says to change to win1, which doesn't show the error but throws it

Full Class:

```
package examplepackage;

//imports
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import examplepackage.location.GetFilepath;

public class Starter {
public static void main(String[] args){
    GetFilepath FP = new GetFilepath();
    JFrame win1 = new JFrame("examplewindow");
    win1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win1.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    win1.pack();
    win1.setSize(600, 800);
    win1.setVisible(true);
    win1.setLocationRelativeTo(win1);
    win1.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(FP + "\\window\\Main").getImage());
}
}
```

Comment: `win1.setLocationRelativeTo(win1);` is this valid?

Comment: I don't see where `emptyLabel` is declared or initialised?

Comment: Hi add  JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel(); on top of  win1.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER); line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on you example, removing the references to `GetFilePath`, as I don't have access to that source, when I compile your code I get...

```
error: cannot find symbol
        win1.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable emptyLabel
  location: class Starter
```

Which basically means that `emptyLabel` is not defined.  It's possible that your IDE is looking for a matching value that could be passed to the method parameter, again, based on you code, that leaves `win1`, which obviously isn't going to work (you can't add something to itself or a `Window` based component to a `Container`)

What you need to to is define and create an instance of some component, such as a `JLabel`, for example...

```
JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel();
win1.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I'd also suggest you have a read through [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and make sure you are initialising your UI's within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: @Karibasappa-G-C already fixed it for me, even though your message is more helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

emmptyLabel is never initialized

Comment: a commenter was better than you(sorry if it sounds mean)